# Add WHERE clause to a query

Tags: sql, where-clause

I have this following query :

```
select count(case when test_nameb is null then 1 end) 
from ( select a.test_name as test_namea, b.test_name as test_nameb 
       from list_52 a 
       left join motorcontroltests b 
       on a.test_name=b.test_name) x
```

With this query, I can count dismatch between two tables on **test_name** column.
But i want to add a **WHERE** clause in this query on the table motorcontroltests. And i have no idea where to put this clause. I tried but always get errors.

Thanks by advance.

Comment: Add the condition to the ON clause in the sub-qeury.

Comment: I think it would be easier to debug if you could show what you tried and the errors you got

Comment: The question and the query do not make perfect sense. Can you add some sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text, not images.

Comment: Here is my fiddle link : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/510da03/3/0
When i add the WHERE clause to the ON, i get count=0 when i should get count=3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try putting `b.version` with `JOIN`:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN b.test_name IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) Count
FROM list_52 a left join motorcontroltests b on a.test_name=b.test_name 
and b.version='2.0'
```

Comment: Ok ! It's now working like I want. Thank you a lot @semicolon !
I didnt need the "where" in my query.

Comment: May I ask why you want to put b.version='2.0' ? It will work even if you don't put this condition

Comment: Because list_52 regroup the list of tests for versions which start with '5.2'. So I have several versions ( 5.2.0, 5.2.1 etc... ) And I have made a website which show which tests we didnt start in my team. All the tests we made are in motorcontroltests table. Thats why i need this condition on motorcontroltests. Because in this table i have a lot of others columns, and the version is a part of it!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what to do with `where` clause but you can avoid `subquery` :

```
select count(*)
from list_52 a
where not exists (select 1 
                  from motorcontroltests b 
                  where a.test_name = b.test_name and b.version = '2.0'
                 );
```

You can directly express it as via `JOIN` :

```
select sum(case when b.test_name is null then 1 else 0 end) 
from list_52 a left join 
     motorcontroltests b 
     on a.test_name = b.test_name and  b.version = '2.0';
```

Comment: Hello. Here is my fiddle link : sqlfiddle.com/#!9/510da03/3/0 When i add the WHERE clause to the ON, i get count=0 when i should get count=3 Same with the join. This query checks the test_name entry in list_52 and count mismatch with test_name in motorcontroltest table. When i dont put WHERE condition i have the right count output. But when i place the WHERE condition, i get count=0 which is not normal –

Comment: @NordineKhilifi. . . Your `where` clause should go with `ON`. Check my edit.

Answer (score 0):

just use `where` clause after join  and later `on`

```
select count(case when test_nameb is null then 1 end) 
from ( select a.test_name as test_namea, b.test_name as test_nameb 
       from list_52 a 
       left join motorcontroltests b 
       on a.test_name=b.test_name    
      where b.test_name is not null --assuming you want to null check---put your condition
     ) x
```

bu i think you can do it by using join

```
select sum(case when b.test_name is null then 1 else 0 end) 
from list_52 a left join 
     motorcontroltests b 
     on a.test_name=b.test_name
```

Comment: Using table b column in WHERE clause would make it into INNER JOIN. I believe it's better to add it among ON conditions.

Comment: @GoranKutlaca i just showed what  OP want his question and just share a thought may be his condition different

Comment: Hello. Here is my fiddle link : sqlfiddle.com/#!9/510da03/3/0 When i add the WHERE clause to the ON, i get count=0 when i should get count=3
Same with the join.
This query checks the test_name entry in list_52 and count mismatch with test_name in motorcontroltest table. When i dont put WHERE condition i have the right count output. But when i place the WHERE condition, i get count=0 which is not normal

Comment: @NordineKhilifi what you put in where clause i just thought you want null check

Answer (score 0):

Although you can write the query as:

```
select count(case when test_nameb is null then 1 end)
from (select l.test_name as test_namea, mct.test_name as test_nameb
      from list_52 l left join
           motorcontroltests mct
           on l.test_name = mct.test_name and mct.version = '2.0'
     ) x;
```

However, this would be more simply written as:

```
select count(*)
from list_52 l left join
     motorcontroltests mct
     on l.test_name = mct.test_name and mct.version = '2.0'
where mct.test_name is null;
```

And perhaps more clearly as:

```
select count(*)
from list_52 l
where not exists (select 1
                  from motorcontroltests mct
                  where l.test_name = mct.test_name and mct.version = '2.0'
                 );
```

Notice that the table aliases are abbreviations for the table names, not arbitrary letters.  This makes it much easier to understand and modify the query.